# Store google translate api results in a database

Tags: mysql, symfony, google-translate

i want to use Google translate REST api, in order to provide auto translations to users of my web site, i'm using symfony for developping. and i want to store results obtained in a  mysql database for futur use.. is that possible ? how can i do that  ?

Answer (score -1):

First in order to use google API, I suggest you this tutorial : [Google API PHP](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-translate-api-php/)
Once you have done that, you just hae to create your database and ORM entity to record the translation.

BUT, if you want to have a multilanguage website, check the official documentation : [Internationalization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/i18n.html), this is the best practise.

Comment: no my aim is not the have a multilanguage website, it about translate some expressions in several languages in real time in order to show these expressions to users

Comment: Ok so, everythings you need is there : [Google API PHP](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-google-translate-api-php/). Create a service that will use this API. And every time a translation is done, the service will save it in the database.

Comment: According to the ToS of Google Translate API it's not 
allowed to store results in a database  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/arzNr0QSNww

Comment: Google now provides a PHP client library: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/php

Comment: The current ToS of Google Translation API seem to have no restrictions regarding storage of the translated data (Google itself will delete the translated data after processing) - https://cloud.google.com/translate/data-usage